# Angular app's dropdown value not pre-populated

Tags: angular, primeng

I have created a form where ALL the fields are populated except dropdown

```
      async initForm() {
    
        this.discpForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          action: ["", [Validators.required]],
         
...
          status: ["In Progress", [Validators.required]],    // In Progress, Voided, Closed
    
          // more items, offense items, evaluator,
          offenses: this.formBuilder.array([]),
          evaluators: this.formBuilder.array([]),
        })
    
        // fetch offense defns, fetch all users
        Promise.all([
         ... series of DB fetch
          this.afStore.doc(`/clients/${this.clientCode}/Performance/OffenseDefns`)
            .ref
            .get()
            .then(res => {
              if (res.exists) {
                let offenses = res.data()
                Object.keys(offenses).forEach(k => {
                  this.optOffenses.push({ label: offenses[k].descr, value: k })
                })
              }
            })
        ])
    
      }
```

[image]
I highlighted the error with red color arrow. These are fields fetched from my DB. There ain't any console error.

```
  async initDetails() {
    this.initForm()

    // populate data
    this.discpForm.patchValue(this.discpDoc)
    this.discpForm.get('reportedDate').setValue(new Date(this.discpDoc.reportedDate.seconds * 1000))

    // ...
    this.discpDoc.offenses.forEach(e => {
      this.addOffense(e)
    })
  }

  offenses(): FormArray {
    return this.discpForm.get('offenses') as FormArray
  }
  newOffense(data: any = {}): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      offense: [data.hasOwnProperty('offense') ? data.offense : '', [Validators.required]],
      reportedDate: [data.hasOwnProperty('reportedDate') ? new Date(data.reportedDate.seconds * 1000) : '', [Validators.required]],
      reportedBy: [data.hasOwnProperty('reportedBy') ? data.reportedBy : '', [Validators.required]],
    })
  }
  addOffense(data: any) {
    this.offenses().push(this.newOffense(data))
  }
```

template logic, it should populate the text field, date field, dropdown with values as the logic push via patchValue and list of value assigned via method 'newOffense()'

```
<div class="p-field p-col-3 _float-ui-spacing_">
                    <span class="p-float-label">
                      <p-dropdown [options]="optOffenses" formControlName="offense">
                      </p-dropdown>
                      <p-message severity="error" text="Offense Code is required"
                        *ngIf="!item.get('offense').valid&&item.get('offense').dirty">
                      </p-message>
                      <label>Offense</label>
                    </span>
                  </div>
```

Comment: I think you could read this for form array: https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a

Comment: I don't know about your `optOffenses` array, but be careful, if is an array of objects (not a simple array of strings) you need use `optionValue`, see the docs of p-dropdown:https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dropdown.

Comment: @Eliseo - thanks for the sample code. I changed my flow to fetch DB's setup and populate values in construct() {} section (consume more db fetch resource, fetch everytime component refresh, but better than not populate correctly)

Answer (score 0):

I thought the [(ngModel)] bound the control:

```
<p-dropdown id='JobId' name='JobId'
  [options]='employeeData.JobTitles'
  (ngModelChange)='formChange($event)'
  [style]="{'width':'250px'}" #JobId='ngModel'
  [(ngModel)]='model.JobId' placeholder='Select a job...'
  [disabled]='!admin'>
</p-dropdown>
```

Comment: i am not using ngModel in my components, so i can't comment on that :) so many ways to dev in angular framework really drives me nuts lol

Comment: Yeah, I have a limited style in Angular development.  I have a reference application 'Angular 11 demo-mg11.zip', located https://sites.google.com/a/computersociety.org/default/clients/resources This is our Classic Google site for Ann Arbor Computer Society, I will be moving this site to new Google site before the end of the year.